# Highlight table row inside of another table

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, razor

I have two tables.  One table loads inside of the other table when a link is clicked in the first table.  When the link is clicked I need to highlight the table row of the 2nd table.  I'm not sure how to do this, since each table is in a separate view.  Here's my link inside the first table that will load the second table when clicked.  I've added a css class to this table.  I want this css to highlight the row in the second table.

first table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <a onclick="$('#instantTable tr').addClass('highlighted'); />
    </td>
</tr?
</table>
```

This is the code for the second table in a seperate view:

2nd table

```
    <table class="delay_spiffgranular" id="instantTable">
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Here is the javascript that loads the table inside of the 1st table.

```
 function pullDetails(carrierId, startDate, divid, status) {


        $.get("@Url.Action("getInstantSpiffOrderDetails", "Dashboard")",
            { carrierId: carrierId, startDate: startDate, status:status},
            function (data) {
                $('.' + divid + ' .submitted_details').html(data);
                $('.' + divid).removeClass('carrier-hide');
            });
    }
```

Any idea on how I can highlight the row in the second table when clicking a link in the first table?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PraveenKumar well it's html and razor.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for the down vote.  Do you have anything to add?

Comment: I removed the downvote. Please tag accordingly or just put generated HTML/CSS.

Comment: @PraveenKumar ok thanks for not down voting, and for editing my post.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I will in the future.  thanks.

Comment: Thanks for taking it in the right way. `:)` Who wants to penalize good questions?

Comment: Looking at the (really difficult to read) code, it's hard to see what the actual issue you're having is.  `a` in 1st table hides some rows in 2nd table then loads some data into 2nd row. Within the `success` part of the `$.get`, add the code to highlight the row.   So, questions: how do you want to highlight the row?  What's the actual issue you're having (just don't know where to start? then where did the existing code come from?)

Comment: Maybe you could strip out all the extra code that *isn't* relevant to the *problem*, then it might be easier to see the solution.  Or, start from scratch with really simple tables.   Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve especially the *minimal* part.

Comment: Ok.  I stripped down my question to just see 2 simple tables.  I need to highlight the row in the second table, when the link in the first table is clicked.  Does this clear things up?